# how to load class function extenally from other class

Tags: php

```
class test {
    function callback(){
        echo "Test okay ";
    }   
}


class classload{
    var $class_instance;
    function __construct(){
        spl_autoload_register (array( $this , 'library' ));
    }

    public function __call ($fn , array $args ){
      if(isset( $this ->{ $fn })){
          array_unshift( $args , $this );
          call_user_func_array ( $this ->{ $fn }, $args );
      }
    }

    function library($class){
        $this->{$class} = new $class($this);
        //$this->class_instance = ${$class};
        return $this;
    }
}


 class classtwo {
     protected  $load;
    function __construct(){
        $this->load = new classload(); 
    }
}

class Classone extends classtwo {
    function view(){
        //load and initialise class
        $this->load->library('test');

      //  print_r($this->load->library('test'));
        echo $this->test->callback();
    }
}

  $init = new classone();
  echo $init->view();
```

> return error undefined property classone::$test

and also call object  ->callback() on null

I have tried to change object into variable but am still getting this error.

Comment: I think your concept is not good at all. Your main code should include or have an autoloader which then loads an class whenever used.

Comment: Please try to improve formatting and add some comments in your code. As it stands, it's not super easy to understand

Comment: this prototype of what i want okay i want to load class function from classone (controller) by $this->load->library("classname");  then i can instantiate class method by $this->classname->method(); on classone

if i load test class on classone via $this->load->library("test")  to do " $test = new test();" then on classone we can the call class method by $this->test->some_method(); this is what i want to achieve instead of doing on class one _construct()

Comment: Please edit your question to include all information instead of posting code (and the actual information about what you want) in a comment. Comments can't be formatted and will therefor be very hard to read.

Comment: _Side note:_ Don't use the old `var` syntax when defining class properties. Use `public`, `private` or `protected` instead (depending on your need). The same goes for when defining methods. You do have `public` on some, but just `function` on others. I recommend being consistent and always define the visibility of properties and methods. This is just a suggestion about good practices.

Comment: all classes are on one file so i dont have to include , i want to achieve load class just code igniter framework any idea what is wrong on library fuunction